# Bill Acceptor to Raspberry Pi 3 (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to connect my Bill Acceptor to the Raspberry Pi 3 and read a pulse. Is there any one who knows or have any idea how to make sure the raspberry pi reads the bill acceptor? Yes i use Python for my code. I used this code but it doesn't work any help here?

```
Code: 
#!/usr/bin/python
#######
# This program would generate Squence pulse train on GPIO 7 Pin 26 of P1
#######`
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import sys
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
  print
  GPIO.cleanup()
  sys.exit(0)

def lopper():
  while 1:
    GPIO.output(7,0)
    sleep(0.00025)
    GPIO.output(7,1)
    sleep(0.00025)
    GPIO.output(7,0)
    sleep(0.00005)
    GPIO.output(7,1)
    sleep(0.00025)
    GPIO.output(7,0)
    sleep(0.00065)
    GPIO.output(7,1)
    sleep(0.00025)
    GPIO.output(7,0)
    sleep(0.00045)
    GPIO.output(7,1)
    sleep(0.00005)
    GPIO.output(7,0)
    sleep(0.00025)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal_handler)
print("Press Ctrl+c to Stop Pulse train")
lopper()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error?

Comment: @ElliotRoberts The Raspberry Pi does not read the Bill acceptor at all which is a problem. I need a way to find out that the raspberry pi can read that the bill acceptor is connected to it

Comment: Whelp, try finding where the problem is. Does the `print` work (is the code even running)? Have you been able to get any indication that any of the multiple steps you're trying to implement are working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found a way to use the MDB protocol for integrating Bill and coin acceptors. I used [Qibix MDB](https://qibixx.com/products/mdb-pi-hat/) hat with raspberry pi 2w, 3, 4, and 4b. You can use these [commands](https://docs.qibixx.com/released/mdb-products/operate-a-coin-acceptor) to enable and poll the coin and bill acceptors and map these results with bills or coins. Here is a [tool chest](https://docs.qibixx.com/released/mdb-products/mdb-toolchest) for testing the acceptors via your PC. You can test and use the same commands with the 'serial' python library on raspberry pi.